# How to turn on "smart file size" display in Total Commander?

Tags: total-commander

In previous version it was possible to turn on some setting where files showed their size depending on size in a smart format: 2.5GB, 156 MB, 2.5 kB. Where is that setting in v 8? (x64)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Configuration--> Option--> Tabstops--> Size Display-->Dynamic